# How can I restart MS Word 2011 Mac without automatically opening documents that crashed it the last time?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word-2011

MS Word 2011 Mac crashed with a couple of documents open. When it opens, it reopens the documents and promptly crashes even if I try to immediately close the documents.

How can I start Word without opening any existing documents, but with a blank slate?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested with a crashed app, but System Prefs > General > check 'Close windows when quitting..' might do it.

If not, then perhaps deleting this folder might do it -
`~/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.Word.savedState`

[image]

Comment: I cut to the chase and deleted the contents of the folder you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pressing SHIFT + click to start up Word will disable the auto open of previous Word docs.